# Form is not getting submitted, even if method, action, and button type submit is given

Tags: php, html

Here is my Code i've given everything form method, form action and button type still form is not going to next page. Please help me with it. And thanks in advance!

```
<div class="contact-form-wrap">
    <form id="contactForm" novalidate="true" action="sendmail.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Please enter your name" placeholder="Enter your name">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Please enter your email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" class="form-control" required="" data-error="Please enter your phone number" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="default-btn" style="pointer-events: all; cursor: pointer;">Book Appointment</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you remove the `/` in the action did you also try to leave it empty so it post it to the same php file, is the page reloading or doing nothing? Do you use javascript? if so make sure you dont use an e.preventdefault. Also pointer-events is not needed on a button

Comment: 1. Make sure that this page is not the same file as sendmail.php. 2. Check for any JavaScript that is not use anything to prevent form submit such as `e.preventDefault();`, or `return false;`, or `void();`, etc. 3. Check on sendmail.php file to see that there is no redirect back to this form page.

Answer (score 0):

try **action="sendmail.php"** (no slash)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).